# Impossible to "unwrap" a var from WeatherKit in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, weatherkit

I'd like to "unwrap" the `sunrise` from `dayWeather` but I don't know what I use instead of "Something". I've tried many things without success. Xcode always tells me that "dayWeather is inaccessible". Do you know what can I use?

```
extension "Something" {
    public var unwrappedSunrise: Date {
        dayWeather.first?.sun.sunrise ?? Date()
    }
}
```

Here's the `WeatherManager` I've got from a nice dude on SO.

```
@MainActor
final class WeatherManager: ObservableObject {
    enum LoadingState {
        case idle
        case loading
        case loaded(CurrentWeather, Forecast<DayWeather>)
        case failed(Error)
    }

    @Published var loadingState: LoadingState = .idle

    init() {
        loadingState = .loading
        Task {
            await requestWeather()
        }
    }

    func requestWeather() async {
        let location = CLLocation(latitude: 48.856613, longitude: 2.352222) /* Paris, France */

        let nowDate = Date.now
        let sevenDaysFromDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 7, to: nowDate) ?? Date()

        let currentWeather: WeatherQuery = .current
        let dailyWeather: WeatherQuery = .daily(startDate: nowDate, endDate: sevenDaysFromDate)

        do {
            let (currentWeather, dayWeather) = try await WeatherService.shared.weather(for: location, including: currentWeather, dailyWeather)
            loadingState = .loaded(currentWeather, dayWeather)
        } catch {
            loadingState = .failed(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks, in advance!

Comment: Probably something g like “Forecast<DayWeather>” what is the point of all this unwrapping? Isn’t is better to show Views based on what you actually have instead of bits and pieces and what may or may not be true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
extension Forecast<DayWeather> {
    public var unwrappedSunrise: Date {
        self.forecast.first?.sun.sunrise ?? Date()
    }
}
```

and call it like this

```
  let sunrise = dayWeather.unwrappedSunrise
```

but as mentioned this is hidden code, you are better off using

```
let sunrise = dayWeather.forecast.first?.sun.sunrise ?? Date()
```

then you know exactly what your code is doing.

You could also use a function (eg in your WeatherManager) such as:

```
func unwrappedSunrise(_ dayWeather: Forecast<DayWeather>) -> Date {
    dayWeather.forecast.first?.sun.sunrise ?? Date()
}
```

and call it like this inside `WeatherManager`:

```
  let sunrise = unwrappedSunrise(dayWeather)
```

or, outside

```
  let sunrise = weatherManager.unwrappedSunrise(dayWeather)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed.